# Ansible --become not working when “sudo with NOPASSWD” is not activated on remote machine - MODULE FAILURE

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

In remote server, normal user is having sudo access but NOPASSWD not activated. sudo su - command ask for user password. I am trying to run a command using Ansible as providing sudo password but its not working getting "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error" error. Please check below logs.

Inventory file

```
[root@**-*****2 ~]# cat inventory
[prod]
10.***.***.250 ansible_user=m**** ansible_password=*******
```

Its working with normal user

```
[root@****** ~]# ansible prod -m ping
10.***.***.250 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

But when i switch to become

```
[root@****** ~]# ansible prod -m ping --become
10.***.***.250 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Missing sudo password"
}
```

when i provide Sudo Password.

```
[root@****** ~]# ansible prod -m ping --become -K
BECOME password:
10.***.***.250 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.***.***.250 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

the verbose output of above error is

```
10.***.***.250 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 21356\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\nShared connection to 10.***.***.250 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

It is working where sudo with NOPASSWD activated. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This questions has been answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870083/specify-sudo-password-for-ansible

Mainly look for part where they discuss `--ask-sudo-pass`